# How to test that my service returns data with jasmine and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

I've begun using jasmine to test my controllers in angularjs however after reading some tutorials I am a bit stuck.

I have this simple angularjs controller called jasmineController

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp');

    myAppModule.controller('jasmineController', ['$scope', 'genericService',
        function ($scope, genericService) {
            $scope.name = 'Superhero';
            $scope.counter = 0;
            $scope.$watch('name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
            });

            $scope.testPromise = function() {
                return genericService.getAll("dashboard", "currentnews", null, null, null);
            }

            $scope.getNewsItems = function () {
                genericService.getAll("dashboard", "currentnews", null, null, null).then(function (data) {

                    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
                    $scope.newsItems = data;

                });
            }

        }
    ]);
})();
```

In my jasmine test I wanted to call getNewsItems and check that it can call genericService.getAll and that $scope.newsItems is assigned some data. I understand that I would be mocking out the service and I won't actually call it.

Here is my spec

```
describe("test", function () {
    // Declare some variables required for my test
    var controller, scope, genericService;

    // load in module
    beforeEach(module("myApp"));


    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _genericService_) {
        genericService = _genericService_;
        // assign new scope to variable
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('jasmineController', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    }));
    it('sets the name', function () {
        expect(scope.name).toBe('Superhero');
    });

    it('should assign data to scope', function() {
        //var fakeHttpPromise = {success: function () { }};
        scope.getNewsItems();
        spyOn(genericService, 'getAll');
        expect(genericService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dashboard', 'currentnews');
    });

});
```

I've got a spyon for genericService.getall() but apart from that I am a bit stuck with checking that my scope variable is assigned a value.

I also get this stack trace:

```
Error: Expected spy getAll to have been called with [ 'dashboard', 'currentnews' ] but it was never called.
   at stack (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1441:11)
   at buildExpectationResult (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1408:5)
   at expectationResultFactory (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:533:11)
   at Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:293:5)
   at addExpectationResult (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:477:9)
   at Anonymous function (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1365:7)
   at Anonymous function (file:///C:/Projects/2013/AMT2015/AMT2015.WebAPP/Scripts/tests/controllers/dashboardControllerSpec.js:49:9)
   at attemptSync (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1759:9)
   at QueueRunner.prototype.run (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1747:9)
   at QueueRunner.prototype.execute (file:///C:/Users/nickgowdy/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Microsoft/VisualStudio/12.0/Extensions/4sg2jkkc.gb4/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1733:5)
```

Comment: you need to return genericService.getAll for testing purpose then only you can test

Comment: @ngLover Would I have to call : spyOn(genericService, 'getAll').andReturn(fakeHttpPromise) ? I had this in my code before but it doesn't pass the test with this neither.

Comment: also try passing null in toHaveBeenCalledWith

Comment: From your controller you can return genericService so you can make your test call async and then can check scope variable to be assigned

Comment: @ngLover Would it be possible to post some code? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
describe("test", function () {
    // Declare some variables required for my test
    var controller, scope, genericService;

    // load in module
    beforeEach(module("myApp"));


    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$q_, _genericService_) {
        genericService = _genericService_;
        var deferred = _$q_.defer();
        deferred.resolve('resolveData');
        spyOn(genericService, 'getAll').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('jasmineController', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
    }));
    it('sets the name', function () {
        expect(scope.name).toBe('Superhero');
    });

    it('should assign data to scope', function() {
        //spyOn(genericService, 'getAll').and.callFake(function() {

        //});
        scope.getNewsItems();
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.newsItems).toBe('resolveData');
        //expect(genericService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dashboard', 'currentnews', null, null, null);

    });

});
```

Because my test is more than just calling a service but handling a promise as well I had to inject *$q*. Then with spy on I say to call service and method and the return value is the deferred promise.

Finally I can look at the scope variable to see if anything is assigned with this line:

```
expect(scope.newsItems).toBe('resolveData');
```

Thanks to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the spy first before calling the test function. And you are you actually passing more parameters to the service function. So you need to test with the exact parameter list.

```
it('should assign data to scope', function() {
        //var fakeHttpPromise = {success: function () { }};
        spyOn(genericService, 'getAll');
        scope.getNewsItems();
        expect(genericService.getAll).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dashboard', 'currentnews',null,null,null);
    });
```

Comment: You're correct, if I call  $scope.testPromise my test passes but if I call $scope.getNewsItems it doesn't. Most of my angular code in my controllers follows $scope.getNewsItems where the function doesn't return anything but with in the code it assigns the resolved promise to another scope variable.

Comment: Do you know how I would test getNewsItems? As far as I can see, they both use genericservice but getNewsItems has an annoymous function after .then